# Android notification of database updated without gcm services

Tags: php, android, mysql

thank your demo,

I have done it . but now i want a notification in android whenever my database updated then a notification mail should be generate  in my android.

i dont want to use GCM service . so please give me a better approach.

thank you 
rahul rawat

Comment: What demo are you referring to?

Comment: This post has completed by me. but now i am not studying about gcm services . Thank  you.  now i am learning about multitouch zoom with scroll and goto next and previous images.  could you help me. i am new in android and wanna make his career in android . thank you